# How do I consistently query dbpedia for programming languages by name?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

There seems to be no consistent way to query for programming languages based on name. Examples:

```
http://dbpedia.org/page/D_(programming_language)
rdfs:label "D (programming language)"@en
dbpprop:name "D programming language"
owl:sameAs freebase:"D (programming language)"
foaf:name "D programming language"
```

vs.

```
http://dbpedia.org/page/C++
rdfs:label "C++"@en
dbpprop:name "C++"
owl:samwAs freebase:"C++"
foaf:name "C++"
```

Since there's no standard convention for whether "programming language", "(programming language)", "programming_language", "(programming_language", or "" is part of a name for a programming language in dbpedia, I have no idea how to consistently search by name.

I'd like to create some sort of SPARQL query that returns http://dbpedia.org/page/D_(programming_language) for "D" and http://dbpedia.org/page/C++ for "C++", but I don't know how do to this.

Unless at least one of the various triples for programming languages uses a consistent naming convention, I'll have to hack it by querying first against name + " (programming_language)", and falling back to name + "(programming language", name + " programming language" when no results are found. But I'd like a much more robust method.

Comment: Maybe there isn't one? It seems sketch to try and use the name as some form of tag/semantic marker. C++ was already "well established" while D (the programming language) is relatively new. It also, for some grand reason, chooses a terribly common "name". E.g. what would happen when dealing with Ruby?

Comment: That is, why not use the ontology/properties instead? e.g. http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Programming_languages

Comment: @pst The big picture is that I want to make a program that, given a programming language name, such as "Python" or "QML", displays a visual graph of its relation to other programming languages. The Programming_language category will ensure that my query results are all the right type, but that doesn't help me find a language resource by name.

Answer (score 4):

You could of course just match using a basic substring match or a regex, e.g. like this to find a match for "C++":

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?pl ?label
WHERE { 
    ?pl a dbpedia-owl:ProgrammingLanguage ;
        rdfs:label ?label .
    FILTER(langMatches(lang(?label), "en"))
    FILTER(regex(str(?label), "C\\+\\+")) 
}
```

Of course, the above will be problematic for a programming language name like "D", since you will get back several matches ("D", "Dylan", "MAD", etc.). In those cases, you might want to do some clever postprocessing of the result, for example tokenizing the returned label and seeing if your input string occurs as a standalone word.

Regex matching in SPARQL is notoriously expensive (in terms of evaluation time), but since you combine it with a type constraint to a particular category, the DBPedia endpoint should be able to handle this kind of query just fine.

Comment: "you might want to do some clever postprocessing" and "Regex matching in SPARQL is notoriously expensive" indicates that this is not a fully formed solution.

Comment: You could perhaps petition the DBPedia maintainers to preprocess this, snipping off (or adding) common pre- or suffixes in labels, so that they are more regular in the DBpedia database, but until that happens you are stuck with regexes and clever postprocessing (which will work well enough), or an alternative approach (e.g. a dropdown list for your users, instead of a keyword search field).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
SELECT distinct ?pl ?label
WHERE { 
  ?pl a dbpedia-owl:ProgrammingLanguage ;
      rdfs:label ?label.
  ?label bif:contains "'C++'" .
  filter (str (?label) like '%C++%')
  filter (lang(?label)="en")
}
```

`?label bif:contains "'C++'"` would filter to some degree, more specifically to C++, C, Objective-C etc., because ++ would be treated as a noise and excluded from actual search pattern.
After that you have C and need two pluses, so `filter (str (?label) like '%C++%')` would check for them faster than regex.
Add `filter (lang(?label)="en")` or `filter (langmatches(lang(?label),"en"))` or no lang check at all by taste.